# Is there a way to switch the left and right css values when in a right-to-left language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, right-to-left

I'm working on a site that supports many different locales. Our next locale is Hebrew, which is a right-to-left language. I'm setting the `dir=rtl` and `lang=he` on the HTML element, and certain things shift around (as they should).

A lot of the website uses elements with absolute positioning setting the left value. Is there a way to make it so when you are in rtl mode that it would switch it to be the right value?

I know that I could have a `rtl` class on my html element and do css overrides when that class is present, but the project is pretty large and it would not be fun to hunt down all of these occurrences manually.

Comment: I guess there is no inbuild way to do this but that's quite interresting question indeed

Comment: you can set in a global array variable (or in a database and get it with JSON) to set which languages are written from left-to-right and vice versa

Comment: Frameworks like WordPress use an `rtl.css` file for right-to-left languages, so you'd likely have to define a second css file.  As long as all your positioning information is in css, this would work, though javascript methods using a left and right to move things around would also have to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding classes would be more robust, but considering how much no-fun that would be, hunt them down with JavaScript!

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/mJjBNq)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var elsToFlip = $('*')
  elsToFlip.each(function () {
    var pos = $(this).css('position')
      , left = $(this).css('left')

    if (pos === 'absolute' && left !== 'auto') {
      $(this).css({
        left: 'initial'
      , right: left
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Something like this would probably work. I'd probably modify it a bit, but I can't think of any other way to really do this.

Comment: Modify away! It really depends on what the desired result is, but it would definitely work.